# Apply datatable to combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Please help me to rectify this, i'm getting an error (`NullReferenceException`)

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HMCS.exe but was not handled in user code'

CodeBehind -

```
dt = oBALSubLocation.SelectLocation(oBOSubLocation);
cmbSubLocation.ItemsSource = dt;
```

UI -

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbSubLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,41,0,-6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Height="26" FontSize="13" />
```

Comment: UI - <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSubLocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,41,0,-6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Height="26" FontSize="13" />

Comment: yes i get error 'An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HMCS.exe but was not handled in user code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name is the column name you want to display:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>

    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,41,0,-6"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="108" Height="26" FontSize="13" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = GetTable();
        ComboBox.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
    }

    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add("Test1");
        table.Rows.Add("Test2");
        table.Rows.Add("Test3");
        return table;
    }
 }
```

Comment: still the error 'An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in HMCS.exe but was not handled in user code'

Comment: Where exactly does this exception occurs?

Comment: in the following line ComboBox.ItemsSource =  table.AsDataView()

Comment: I updated the answer with all the code, there are no errors and the combobox has the values

Comment: Please explain me how to add value to the following combobox as you add display text ***<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>***